# How can I copy a sheet with vba via macro

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I have a sheet with a marco(from excel vba):

```
Rem Attribute VBA_ModuleType=VBADocumentModule
Option VBASupport 1
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
...
End Sub
```

It can work right.

But after I copy the sheet to a new sheet, the new sheet will lose the macro.

So I try write a Sheet Event of Double Click, and write a marco to copy the sheet and event.

```
Sub CopySheetWithEvents()
    oSheets = ThisComponent.Sheets
    oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    sName = oSheet.Name
    sNewName = oSheets.Count + 1
    oSheets.CopyByName(sName, sNewName, oSheets.Count + 1)

    oNewSheet = oSheets(oSheets.Count - 1)
    aSheetEvents = oSheet.Events
    sEventNames = aSheetEvents.ElementNames
    aNewSheetEvents = oNewSheet.Events
    For i = 0 To ubound(aSheetEvents.ElementNames)
        aEvent = aSheetEvents.getbyname(sEventNames(i))
        aNewSheetEvents.ReplaceByName(sEventNames(i), aEvent)
    Next i
End Sub
```

It is Ok, but Sheet Event hasn't a "Cancel" parameter which my macro need.

How can I copy the sheet with vba?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently sheet events do not take parameters.  I right-clicked on the Sheet 1 tab, selected `Sheet Events`, and assigned `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` to the Double click event.  Then, double clicking produced the following error message:

> A Scripting Framework error occurred while running the Basic script  Standard.Module2.Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick.
>
> Message: wrong number of parameters!

If we instead assign it to a macro that does not take arguments:

```vb
Sub DoDoubleClick
    MsgBox "Double clicked"
End Sub
```

Then double clicking produces the intended result.  Also your `CopySheetWithEvents()` will create a new sheet and correctly assign the event to the new sheet.

So, I think you need to rewrite `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` so that it does not require arguments.  To get the range, read the current selection:

```vb
oSelect = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection.getRangeAddress
```